# Github account issue

Tags: git, github

I am new on GitHub. when I commit after that GitHub shows unknown name in the contributors list

My account https://github.com/jay-thanki

### GitHub shows this account  https://github.com/nagasurya

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably should check the git username set onto your machine.

Here are some links for your reference.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git

Answer (score 0):

I am using Github Desktop app for commiting the code so there i wrote wrong email by doing correct email i was able to solve this issue which i was facing on GitHub. 
[image]